# List of StopWords in Postgres 9.1

Tags: postgresql

What is the list of stop words (ignored words) used by Postgres when doing fulltext searches?  Is there a way I can find this out (by running a query or something)?

So you know what I'm looking for, here is the list from MySQL.  I'm guessing the Postgres one is similar http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS

The location of stopwords for english dictionary is: `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/english.stop` for instance: `/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/tsearch_data/english.stop`

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for.  I hadn't read the documentation carefully enough to find it.

Comment: You can find the share dir by running `pg_config --sharedir`

Answer (score 4):

For Homebrew users on MacOS you can find the Postgres StopWord files here:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/<%version%>/share/postgresql/tsearch_data
```

Alternatively the up-to-date list is available on Github:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/snowball/stopwords